# Alternative to pack()

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a terrain generator, and I am loading upwards of a million JPanels into my frame, and that takes more than an hour. I have isolated most of the problem in the `pack()` method. Are there any alternatives to using it, or maybe a way to do it faster? Here is some of my code:

```
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));
    System.out.println("Generating...");
    Chunk spawnChunk = new Chunk(this.mapSize);
    System.out.println("Done\nAdding Tiles...");
    for (double[] row : Chunk.tileData) {
        for (double d : row) {
            int v = (int) (20 - d / 500);
            if(v < 0) {
                v = 0;
            }
            else if (v > 20){
                v = 20;
            }
            add(new Tile(v, tileSize));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done\nPacking...");
    pack();
    System.out.println("Done\nRepainting...");
    repaint();
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Note: Tile is just a JPanel with a background color

Comment: Of course. *Don’t add a million `JPanel`s into a frame*. That’s surely not productive. Further, `FlowLayout` isn’t the right layout for a tiled terrain. Consider using a `JTable` with a custom cell render, just as an example.

Comment: `setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));` - don't use magic numbers. One of those number is used for the layout alignment. Use the file provided by the API. I have no idea if 0 is right/left/center. Make your code easy to read and understand

Comment: JPanel has way too much overhead for what (it seems) you are trying to do.  Think Java2D for this, rather than Swing.  You want to **draw** not use widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lot of JPanels. My recommendation - if 'Tile is just a JPanel with a background color', then just do the custom drawing yourself using a single JPanel. Override the paintComponent method and use the passed Graphics object to draw the colors.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);  
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfTiles; i++ ){
        g.setColor(colorOfCurrentTile);
        g.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of a simple implementation of this?

Comment: Answer edited width some abstract code to work from.

Comment: @Asourcious, Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for the basics. There is more to painting then just the painting code. You also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: Added super's call. Don't leave this out.